# Azure Cloud service deploy under not owner

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

My customer added my microsoft profile to his subscription as owner.

[image]

I logged to Visual Studio with this profile and try to publish cloud service. But I get an error:

[image]

why so and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User should be added as co-administrator, not only as owner. More information about it here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/

Ability to add user as co-administrator is already added to new portal (and deprecated on old portal):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Cloud services are not available in this subscription.

This error is caused because for Azure Service Management (ASM) resources you should be **co-admin** in order to deploy services.

If you look on the new portal, you can see that you have permission for publishing on this subscription but one thing to keep in mind is that this “**Owner**” role is **only** valid for Azure Resource Manager resources. Even though you can manage Cloud Services on the new portal, it is an ASM resource and that’s why this role is not applicable for it. Roles configured on the new portal are RBAC and they are only valid for ARM resources.

So, **you should ask for the subscription an Admin to add your user as** **co-admin** **on the [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).**

More information about `co-admin` and `owner`, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2016/07/05/cloud-services-are-not-available-in-this-subscription/).

[image]

**Update:**

Sorry for my mistake.

For now, we should use new portal to add `co-administrator`, like this:

[image]

More information about add Co-administrator via new portal, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator).

Comment: i doubt that this is how this works given that cloud services are fully migrated to arm

Comment: old portal says :" Co-Administrator management is now available only in the new Azure portal.
Learn how co-administrator management has changed in the new portal.
Get started with the new portal and visit Subscriptions."

Comment: @OlegSh Sorry for my mistake, you are right, we should add co-administrator via Azure new portal, I have update my answer, please check it.